# Why is it “tuck in” and not just “tuck”?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is there a rule for when to use ‘in’ as in “tuck in”? Or is it a thing to remember?

Example: *Tuck **in** your shirt*

Comment: For what meaning of "tuck"/"tuck in"?

Comment: Usually 'tuck' requires 'in. Please give a complete sentence as an example of how you would like to use it. That way we can explain it better.

Comment: "Tuck in your shirt"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - 'tuck' does not necessarily require 'in'. 'to tuck' is normal verb and 'to tuck in' in a phrasal verb. These two have slightly but significantly different meanings. E.g. "She had a doll tucked under her arm."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tuck
>  
>   *verb*
>   (*tucks*, present participle *tucking*; past and past participle *tucked*)
>   (transitive) To pull or gather up (an item of fabric). [From 14thc.]
>   (transitive) To push into a snug position; to place somewhere safe or somewhat hidden. [From 1580s.]
>
> - **Tuck in** your shirt.
> - I **tucked in** the sheet.
> - He **tucked** the $10 bill **into** his shirt pocket.
> - *It was flood-tide along Fifth Avenue; motor, brougham, and victoria swept by on the glittering current; pretty women glanced out from limousine and tonneau; young men of his own type, silk-hatted, frock-coated, the crooks of their walking sticks **tucked up** under their left arms, passed on the Park side*.
>      <sub>*[The Younger Set](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=T-yPDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=%22swept%20by%20on%20the%20glittering%20current%22%20%22their%20walking%20sticks%20%22tucked%20up%20under%20their%20left%20arms%22&source=bl&ots=brhoAOwf1n&sig=xqjXSkxsDoAXb4-nl2nNGcJ-8Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWzbiM-cLeAhUEV7wKHVqKAp0Q6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22swept%20by%20on%20the%20glittering%20current%22%20%22their%20walking%20sticks%20%22tucked%20up%20under%20their%20left%20arms%22&f=false)* By  Robert William Chambers</sub>

As you can see tuck used to mean both to pull  and push , so you need to specify it with a preposition the 'direction' of your action. Even though tuck doesn't mean 'pull' anymore, you still need to specify where you 'tucked' your shirt; as in into your pants / under the blanket / behind other folded clothes in your drawer etc .

> English Offline Dictionary by Livio

Comment: Yes, in general *tuck* requires a preposition. It is often ’in’ it doesn’t always have to be.

Comment: It looks likely that you copied this from a dictionary. Please cite and quote it.

Comment: I tidied up the formatting of this answer a bit as I thought it was just one massive block of text, difficult to understand. Feel free to make any changes. Also, since much of it seems to be quoted, it would be a good idea to add a link to the source .

Comment: **Tuck in** could also referring to eating a meal, which is why context is needed.

Comment: @kevin Yes , I did so that my answer seems credible. Although I don't exactly know the name of the dictionary , it's the top rated english to english offline one that's on playstore.

Comment: @Zebrafish , Thank you ! I tried to put it in paragraphs but I just didn't know how.

Comment: I did not consider two directions in this word. Thank you!